# Facebook Share ignores empty open graph description

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph

For our website, we are including the following open graph metatag to provide a description for Facebook shares.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="User provides optional content here..." />
```

For the description, we include some user supplied data.  However, this data field is optional.  What we have found is that if we leave the content attribute as an empty string, Facebook appears to ignore the metatag altogether and uses the first paragraph tag in the document. I wouldn't expect Facebook to do this.

We would prefer to not provide a default description in these cases. Is there a workaround for this or are we doing something else wrong?  Anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: AFAIK, that meta tag can't be empty or dynamically populated. You will need to fill in static description text there, since the facebook scrapper uses it. You can run your url through the linter tool to check and see what og meta tags have been parsed by fb here - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I realize it can't be dynamically populated but I can't see why we can't leave this blank? Why can we not suppress facebook from putting in a description that we don't want? We have had this functionality for quite some time actually but we have only noticed this behavior recently which makes me wonder if something didn't change on Facebook's end.

Comment: Additionally, I have run the page through the debug tool. It recognizes that the description is blank. No where does the debug tool show the text that is actually used when we share the page to facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a dev environment setup outside of the firewall so I could test some workarounds. Looks like all I have to do is output a space if there is no description.

Comment: Now that does not work, however entering an another invisible character like `&nbsp;` helps. Looks like FB `trim()`s all the whitespace from `og:description` value but honors HTML entities